# Redirect to another controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on project with Codeigniter. I am stuck in controller problems. Here is my folder schema looks like :

```
application
 /controller
  /management
    dashboard_controller.php // Dashboard Management
  /administrator
    dashboard_controller.php // Dashboard Administrator
```

I tried to access ***dashboard_controller.php*** using ***redirect()*** function.
Here is my Controller :

```
...
else{
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $password = $this->input->post('password');

   if($this->login_model->get_user_login('$username', '$password')){
      redirect('management/dashboard_controller/index');
```

Here is my Model :

```
public function get_user_login($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');
    return $this->verify_hash($password, $hash);
}
```

But, it doesn't works. Can you guys explain to me? Or Codeigniter routes doesn't support such configuration? Thank you.

Comment: redirect wants a uri, not necessarily the controller name if your routes table remaps www.example.com/test_a/test_a_controller. Is `test_a/test_a_controller/index.php` a valid address?

Comment: Meant to say, is `sitename.com/test_a/test_a_controller` a valid address? =(

Comment: Hi, Few things to check make sure you have properly named the class and file name explained here codeigniter way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming you also may need to place a htaccess in main directory https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @ourmandave sitename.com/test_a/test_a_controller.php, test_a_controller.php already a file, not folder

Comment: @wolfgang1983 already done. thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: @BektiGalan Try and be more clear in your question. show full code where the redirect it. Re edit your question.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Edited. I am sorry I can't show more. I just curious about calling controller inside a folder. Is it allowed or not? Thanks

Comment: I see you have single quote on controller `('$username', '$password')` replace it `($username, $password)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try with below:

```
redirect(base_url() . 'test_a/test_a_controller');
```

Comment: it should be base_url('url something'); doesn't it? And yes, i have tried it. It doesn't work

Comment: You can write base_url() with both and both are worked as same @BektiGalan

Comment: No need to add base_url() at all.
it could just be `redirect('test_a/test_a_controller');`

Answer (score 0):

Example below

filename: `management/Login.php`

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('login_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    $isValid = $this->login_model->get_user_login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'))

    if ($isValid) {
      // You by default will redirect to the index function so not need index at end.
      redirect('management/dashboard_controller');

    }

  }

}
```

Model

```
public function get_user_login($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $hash = $query->row()->password;

    return $this->verify_hash($password, $hash); Make sure Returns TRUE / FALSE
}
```

I think your using password_verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

```
public function verify_hash($password, $hash) {
   if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return FALSE;
   }
}
```

When need to create a password use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how you will need to redirect using base_url:

```
redirect(base_url('management/dashboard_controller/index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter the URL is built in the following way:

> controller/method/id

I haven't seen anyone place controller files in a sub-directory in 'controller/' before. My guess would be if you're trying to redirect to

> management/dashboard_controller/index

where management is the inner directory, dashboard_controller is the controller, and index is the method you could accomplish that by doing:

```
header("Location:".base_url()."management/dashboard_controller");
```

The reason you don't need to explicitly call the method 'index()' is because Codeigniter does that for you automatically. If there is another method within your controller aside from index() and you're trying to redirect to it, then you'd have to explicitly type 'dashboard_controller/foo'.